# Problem with a child tag where the link is not working due to the parent tag

Tags: html, angular

Child tag link is not working because of parent tag link is there any solution for this please suggest me here is the code:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap mx-auto mb-4">
     <a [routerLink]="['/manager/stores', (store$ | async)?.id, 'locations', location.id, 'manage']" class="d-block w-18 mx-2 pl-2 my-2 py-2 border border-primary rounded" *ngFor="let location of (locations$ | async).data">{{ location.label | uppercase }}<i [routerLink]="['/manager/stores', (store$ | async)?.id, 'orders']" [queryParams]="{locationId: location.id}" class="fas fa-shopping-cart float-right mr-2"  title="{{'admin.store.statistics.orders'|translate}}"></i><i class="far fa-clipboard float-right mr-2" title="{{'admin.store.statistics.orderCapture'|translate}}"></i></a>
</div>
```

Both I tag is inside the anchor tag are type of buttons:

[image]

Comment: Very hard to understand what you want to do, and what is wrong in what you did. Can you please edit your question and add more details about what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

it's a really hard link (and you has a link into another link). I try to divide into lines your code, but I can not get so much sense. I think that you need three links -the first and last one is the same route

You can use the *ngIf let to get the value of store$|async and ng-container to make more clear

Sure I'm wrong, but should be some like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{store:store$ | async} as store">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap mx-auto mb-4"
      *ngFor="let location of (location$|async).data">
        <a class="d-block w-18 mx-2 pl-2 my-2 py-2 border border-primary rounded"
        [routerLink]="['/manager/stores/'+store.store?.id+'/'locations/'`+location.id+'/manage'">
           {{ location.label | uppercase }}
        </a>
        <a>
           <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart float-right mr-2"  
              title="{{'admin.store.statistics.orders'|translate}}"
              [routerLink]="['/manager/stores/'+store.store?.id+'/orders']" 
              [queryParams]="{locationId: location.id}" >
           </i>
        </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/manager/stores/'+store.store?.id+'/'locations/'`+location.id+'/manage'">
           <i class="far fa-clipboard float-right mr-2" 
              title="{{'admin.store.statistics.orderCapture'|translate}}">
          </i>
        </a>
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: No first thing it break the design of the card, I mean both icon button are outside with main button and I want to both Icon button inside the main button. What I am thinking to divide this in to the three i tag and give them respectd link instead of inherit the a tag link. So the first i tag is with table name and the link which is in the anchor tag and then second i tag with same link which already have it and for third i tag I need to add the link, By the wah thanks for your suggestions